# Is declaring a redundant output a problem?

Tags: openmdao

If one of my components has 2 outputs where the first one is connected to the following component and the second one is just redundant and used for my own bookkeeping and recording. 
Partials for the second one are not declared (neither by saying dependent=False).

Will this be a problem and cause confusion for calculating total derivatives? If so what would the best way be if I wanted to add extra variables via openmdao default recorders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will generally only be a problem if the second output is involved in the optimization (if it's used as a constraint or objective).  Otherwise its derivatives shouldn't factor into the problem at all.

Comment: Ok thanks. Though i said not declared in my question, I guess it would increase computations unnecessarily per component if it was sth like this self.declare_partials('*','*','fd')

Comment: Actually, extra outputs won't substantially increase the cost of FD. the cost of FD scales with the size of the input vector.